# SetViewValue in directive does not update the actual value in angular model

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I have a pop-up which inputs a value and save the value before closing the pop-up.
If I enter a valid amount for the input, the code works fine. But if I entered an invalid value (ex: input amount = 'USD 100')
this validates properly and display the value as 100 in my textbox, but when I try to save the value it passes as SD 100 to my angular model.

javascript

```
angular.module('app').directive('decimalOnly', ['$http', function ($http) {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    scope: {
      allowNegative: '@'
    },

    link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {

        var negative = '';

        if (!inputValue) {
          return '0.00';
        }

        if (attrs.allowNegative == 'true') {
          negative = '\-';
        }

        var regex = new RegExp('[^0-9\.' + negative + ']', '');

        var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(regex, '');
        if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
          modelCtrl.$render();
        }

        return transformedInput;
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="form.amount" decimal-only />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might help

```
 angular.module('app').directive('decimalOnly', ['$http', function ($http) {
      return {
       require: '?ngModel',
     scope: {
       allowNegative: '@'
      },

      link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
  modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {

    var negative = '';

    if (!inputValue) {
      return '0.00';
    }

    if (attrs.allowNegative == 'true') {
      negative = '\-';
    }

    var regex = new RegExp('[^0-9\.' + negative + ']', '');
      if(negative){
         var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(regex, '');
   }
        var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/\D/g,'');
    var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(regex, '');
    if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
      modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
      modelCtrl.$render();
    }

    return transformedInput;
  });
}
```

};
}]);

Comment: Tried again, but this is working same as the code I posted

Comment: sorry can you remove this line var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(regex, '');  which i have put after if condtion